# ios7 Deallocation of a UITableView embedded in a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I am just about to submit my first app and I am using Xcode Instruments to perform a memory analysis on my app. I can see that once the view is allocated, the memory is not released, despite selecting another view using the `TabBarController`.

I have written some code in the function `ViewDiddisappear`: to set the view to nil. From a persistence point of view it is OK. Additionally the memory not in view is released. However I am not certain if it the best way to release memory not in view. One side effect of this method is that when the view is recreated by the selection of the `TabBarController`, the view (`TableView`) seems to forget that it in a `TabBarController` with a navigation bar at the top. The view seems shifted up a bit as if it isn't aware of the navigation bar at the top of the screen.

I have been googling about, both in apple documentation and on the web. It isn't clear what is the best way to deallocate a `TableViewController` when it isn't in view, and any comments on memory allocation when using `TabBarController`.

I would appreciate some expertise to help me get my memory management right before I submit the app.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tab bar controller allocates memory for all the view controllers inside it.
You are using iOS 7 and it supports ARC(Automatic Reference Counting).
So, you need not to worry about Tabbar Controller memory.

Comment: The reason I  have asked, is that my tabbarcontroller has five view controllers in its' array. If I move from one tab to another, the memory allocated for the previous tab (view controller)is not released, so memory is held and not released even when the view controllers are not on screen. Is that acceptable in the case of the UITabbarcontroller ?